# How to make a view controller adopt the same size as its distant ancestor's container view?

Tags: ios, xcode

This will be easiest to explain with a diagram:

[image]

Here the initial view controller has a container view which contains the tab bar controller (note that the red bar at the top is a view, the initial view controller is NOT a navigation controller).

Any views displayed by the tab bar controller will occupy the same dimensions as the container view. Therefore when the blue VC is displayed the screen will continue to show the red view.
If when the button on the blue VC is clicked the green VC is presented modally and it occupies the full screen and thus covers the red view.

My question is, is there a simple way to make the green view controller occupy the same dimensions as its grand parent's container view so that the red view will be visible when the green VC is displayed.
(By simple, I don't want to do anything involving strong coupling such as the green vc obtaining the explicit dimensions of the container view and setting its dimensions to match. I'm hoping there's a setting in the storyboard or a different way of presenting the vc which will result in it automatically adopting the same size as its parent).

Yes I know the intitial view controller could be a navigation controller, we don't need to discuss why its not.

Comment: You could set a `NSUserDefaults` in the viewDidLoad of the VC you want to model the size from, then call that value later to set dimensions. You'd need to put some sort of handler in in case the value is nil.